# QApplication: No such file or directory

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

I installed QT4 Creator in /usr/programs/qt , I add to PATH /usr/programs/qt/bin,
QTDIR=/usr/programs/qt,LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$QTDIR/lib, and also for  MANPATH and export. Problem is that demo examples work fine, but when I create new project in other directory for example /home/Jane/ it doesn't work, I got errors like

> /home/Jane/test-build-desktop/../test/main.cpp:1:
>   error: QApplication: No such file or
>   directory
>   /home/Jane/test-build-desktop/../test/main.cpp:2:
>   error: QLabel: No such file or
>   directory

```
 #include <QApplication>
 #include <QLabel>
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     QApplication app(argc, argv);
     QLabel *label = new QLabel("Hello Qt!");
     label->show();
     return app.exec();
}
```

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: pls, post up how your *.pro file looks like.

Answer (score 6):

Add to your .pro file:

```
QT += gui
```

Answer (score 6):

I've the same problem. in my ".pro" file it was

```
QT -= gui
```

then I changed it to

```
QT += gui
```

and the problem solved

Answer (score 3):

```
QApplication: No such file or directory ...
```

try to add

QT += widgets

at your .pro file. I had the same message... It looks like from 5.0 Qt-based applications does not like widgets by default...

Answer (score 2):

The solution works for me, Qt 5.7

After added the following line to your .pro file:

```
QT += widgets
```

Right-click on your Qt Project and click "Run qmake"

[Run qmake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLiZK.png)

After this when you re-complie your project, everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If your .pro file has this line:

```
QT       -= gui
```

you need to delete it. It tells that the gui module to be removed from your app.

You can enable it by typing

```
QT       += gui
```

but actually it is not needed since the gui module is enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 14.04 if you get the same error:

```
ABC$ make
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I. -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -o textpad.o textpad.cpp
textpad.cpp:1:24: fatal error: QApplication: No such file or directory
 #include <QApplication>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [textpad.o] Error 1
```

Try `qmake-qt4` and then `make`. Of course you can get all the QT4 libraries if its not present using:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev
```